# Want to get time in my dates as multiple of 5 in SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @StartDate DATETIME = GetDate()
    DECLARE  @increase INT = 5;
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME =  (SELECT DATEADD(mi, @increase,   @StartDate))
    select @StartDate,@EndDate
```

In above query I have increased the current time by 5 min. Now What I want is if the query returns 2020-12-16 09:26:16.103 as start time and 2020-12-16 09:31:16.103 as end time the start time should automatically becomes 2020-12-16 09:25:16.103 and end end time will get increase accordingly by 5 minutes. I hope I am clear.

The answer to above question is below. Postiong so that it will help others

```
Declare @StartDate DATETIME = GetDate() 
set @StartDate=(select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, '1900-01-01', dateadd(second, 150,  @StartDate))/5*5, 0))
    DECLARE  @increase INT = 5;
    DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME =  (SELECT DATEADD(mi, @increase,   @StartDate))
    select @StartDate,@EndDate
```

Comment: Can you provide the data set you have and the desired result?

Comment: yes sure @Emin Mesic

Comment: I have Updated the details in my Question @Emin Mesic

Comment: @jiga It looks like you updated your question with the answer. It'd be preferable to actually post an answer your own question and accept it. Which might seem odd, but SO encourages this when applicable. For one thing it changes your question to the "Answered" status.